# Queried parameter is null

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to query the `pid` parameter of my `http://localhost:3000/edit-product?pid=Z4HLrHGZ1ikKIwlEVkM6` URL.

Here is my code:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.path);
      const pid = params.get("pid");
      console.log("This----->", pid);
```

Each time I run the code, the console prints that the pid value is `null`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `window.location.search`. `window.location.path` is `undefined`.

[MDN: URLSearchParams#Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Examples)

> **Gotchas**
>
> The URLSearchParams constructor does not parse full URLs.
> However, it will strip an initial leading ? off of a string, if
> present.
>
> ```
> var paramsString1 = "http://example.com/search?query=%40";
> var searchParams1 = new URLSearchParams(paramsString1);
>
> searchParams1.has("query"); // false 
> searchParams1.has("http://example.com/search?query"); // true
>
> searchParams1.get("query"); // null
> searchParams1.get("http://example.com/search?query"); // "@" (equivalent to decodeURIComponent('%40'))
>
> var paramsString2 = "?query=value";
> var searchParams2 = new URLSearchParams(paramsString2);
> searchParams2.has("query"); // true 
>
> var url = new URL("http://example.com/search?query=%40");
> var searchParams3 = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
> searchParams3.has("query") // true
> ```

Comment: Still returns undefined. My ```params``` returns an empty object

Comment: Updated to use `search`

Comment: My man JBallin. It worked. Thanks for being such a baller.

Comment: gotta stay drippin. Added an MDN example too.